# Map reduce job throwing "EPERM: Operation not permitted" when using copyToLocalFile(-,-) method.?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

I have written Map-Reduce code to copy a file from HDFS to Local and when i am running Map-Reduce job it is throwing below error.

```
            Log Upload Time: Thu Jun 29 10:51:22 +0530 2017

            Log Length: 78421677

            Showing 1000000 bytes of 78421677 total. Click 
            here
             for the full log.
          t org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:295)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:393)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:435)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:922)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:903)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:800)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:368)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:292)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2016)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1985)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1961)
    at com.mani.pmml_mr.PMMLMapper.map(PMMLMapper.java:64)
    at com.mani.pmml_mr.PMMLMapper.map(PMMLMapper.java:35)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
EPERM: Operation not permitted
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:230)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:708)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:225)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:295)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:393)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:435)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:922)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:903)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:800)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:368)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:341)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.copy(FileUtil.java:292)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:2016)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1985)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.copyToLocalFile(FileSystem.java:1961)
```

In my code i am using **copyToLocalFile()** method but i am not sure why it is throwing errors. I gave full permissions (777) to the local folder where the file will be copied. But still it is throwing some error.

And another problem i noticed is, even the job is throwing error (Which i noticed from Job Browser of Hue), still in console it is showing job is successful.

```
17/06/29 10:51:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1495430640647_0231 completed successfully
```

Can someone please help me in this.

Comment: Is your datanode up and running? Can you see files on hdfs? Is this the entire entire stacktrace or are there 1 or 2 lines above this error?

Comment: Do you have configured cgroups?

Comment: @philantrovert i have verified all data nodes are up and running and i can see files in HDFS. I have updated the log info. Can you please check it again.

Comment: @jedijs: No i have not configured cgroups. Is it mandatory to configure it. I have given 777 permission to both input and output paths.

Comment: You might have given 777 to output directory but `hadoop` might not have enough permissions on the parent directory of `output`. Try setting your output path to `/tmp/output` and see if it works

Comment: @philantrovert: I have done the same. `/tmp/test` i have created and i gave permissions from parent directory.